# How can I return API objects in application using flask

Tags: python, flask, heroku

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/address_search', methods=['GET'])
def sample():
    zipcode = request.args.get('zipcode', None)
    url = f'https://zipcloud.ibsnet.co.jp/api/search?zipcode={zipcode}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    # results = response.json()
    # results = jsonify(response) ?????
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I'm trying to create an Application which return the Address.
I succeeded to return url but about response, I can't and `Internal Server Error` appears
So I thought in flask, `requests.get(url)` cannot be used but I didn't came up an another way.
I heard that `jsonify()` is used but I don't known how.
I searched it in Google for two days but I still cannot find it's answer.
Someone please give me advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to return the response of that API in your web application, i guess this is what you're looking for?

```py
@app.route('/address_search', methods=['GET'])
def sample():
    zipcode = request.args.get('zipcode', None)
    url = f'https://zipcloud.ibsnet.co.jp/api/search?zipcode={zipcode}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    response_json = response.json()
    return jsonify(response_json)
```

EDIT, response to your comment:

You can't do `jsonify(response_json)['results'][0]` because `jsonify` turns the JSON data to Flask `Response` object, instead try this:

```py
@app.route('/address_search', methods=['GET'])
def sample():
    zipcode = request.args.get('zipcode', None)
    url = f'https://zipcloud.ibsnet.co.jp/api/search?zipcode={zipcode}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    response_json = response.json()
    results = response_json['results'][0]
    return jsonify(results)
```

Comment: Yes, Yes, I thought that's didn't work but it did lol Thank you vremes, now I succeeded.

Comment: Ops, I faced another problem. I succeeded to return json object but try to select details like , results = jsonify(response_json)['results'][0], it didn't work. Internal Server Error pops up. How can I do ?

Comment: AHHH okay so jsonify() is Flask Response Object not json Object so that's why! Thank you vremes

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to mark my answer as correct if your issue has been solved.